# How can everyone in a large crowd hear the speaker from a long distance away?

Tags: dialogue, realism

I always wonder about this particular scenario, where in a large area, the lead speaks and all of the audience listen although they are quite far away. In some motivational speeches, the army commander speaks from a long distance and the soldiers get encouraged and respond to it.

This can be observed in many movies/series like:

1. In *Game of Thrones* S08E06, "The Iron Throne", Daenerys' speech be audible to everyone. Also in previous episode, Missandei's words were audible for Dany and her army?
2. In *Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers*, during Saruman's speech to all the orcs, Even though Saruman is at the top of the tower his words/voice wouldn't naturally be discernible from hundreds of feet away.

Comment: This is not a film technique...its a dramatic effect. That said, some people have voices that carry a long way.

Comment: I couldn't find the appropriate tag to my question .

Comment: It's pretty clear what's being asked here. Should definitely reopen.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question exactly is. Do you wonder how can people hear the speaker from so far away or you wonder why people standing in far far away listens to the speaker?

Comment: both @Vishwa, how can people hear the speaker from far away and the people from far away are able to listen to speaker.

Comment: The people who closed this question are probably standing too far away to hear it clearly.

Comment: The purpose of this question is entirely unclear to me. We're not really here to debate the acoustics of the human voice in reality, nor the myriad of scenarios in the 5 million actual films this happens in. What insight do you expect from this question other than "yeah, that's...uh...kinda unrealistic, bro"? You might want to concentrate the question a little more on the filmic aspects of this if that's what you're actually after rather than how the acoustics of crowds actually work, since this isn't Physics.SE.

Answer (score 3):

There are three potential approaches here.

1. The leader's voice carries due to geography/technology/psychic connection
2. People in the front ranks can turn around and tell those behind what's going on
3. (more usually), the ranked masses pretty much understand what's going on and simply yell and stamp their feet when the people in front do

In terms of actually valuable knowledge, this comes in the smaller briefings that come afterward where operational leaders brief their underlings.

Or the entire army marches off to undoubted glory without really needing to know the details.

Comment: #3 is most accurate and has been the case IRL for centuries during field battles and similar. Those in the back/farthest away have no actual idea of what's being said, they just cheer and scream along with everyone else that's closer up.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, **MAYBE YES**

I said maybe because it will need ideal conditions as discussed in this [Physics SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/415409/how-far-can-a-shout-travel) and this [Guiness World Record](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/farthest-distance-travelled-by-a-human-voice).